# Get path to web root directory from IP and current folder

Tags: ubuntu, path

If I am in a folder on ubuntu, say root/API_Project/ and I want to save files from this folder to a folder in the web root directory, how can I programmatically find the path to the web root directory?

For example

```
1] inside the directory root/API_Project/
2] program creates png image
3] program saves png image to web root directory
```

How could the above program be aware that the web root is in ../../../../../var/www/html relative to the root/API_Project/ folder?

Comment: why not directly use /var/www/html?

Comment: I've found that depending on the version of Ubuntu, it's not always var/www/html. Plus it's back 5 folders currently, but if the API folder wasn't where it is not, this wouldn't be back 5 folders. So the user needs to manually check how many folders back from the API folder their root is.

Comment: if you need to go to the root, you don't need to check where you are. Just leave those ../ out.  Now assume the web root is not fixed (or known), then if the program's called within a CGI or the program is a CGI, the CGI should be able to get the web root from one of the environment variables, e.g. DOCUMENT_ROOT, and pass it to the program (or the program could get web root directly from the environment variable).